# Is django-cms frontend editing suitable for a site with rotating parts

Tags: user-interface, frontend, django-cms, edit-in-place

I've got the design for a website ready and now I'd like to implement content management in django. I've got a few years of experience in python development and I've done projects in django. I've looked into django-cms, played around with a demo and set up a quick example. I am happy to use django-cms 3beta2 (and fix some of the possibly occuring bugs on the way).

My question:

The pages of the planned website will consist of different parts, that I could construct from template blocks. The layout of the page is quite rigid, so there is not much possibility for the users to wildly combine template blocks, it would be easy to do frontend editing for an unexperienced editor.

However the webpages also contain a side bar with quotes from famous people and an image. These quotes and images should change randomly on each page load and they are not connected to the main content of the page. Can I still use frontend editing or is there a django-cms plug-in to do so? I image the problem to be that while frontend editing the quote showing up is randomly selected and I can edit the presented quote, but not the other ones. Would I have to ask the editor to resort to the backend? What would be a nice solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently going through old questions that I've asked and that do not have an answer yet. Here is a solution:

One can write a cms plugin for django-cms that contains multiple inner placeholders. These inner placeholders are containers for the "famous quotes". If editing of the page is not active, the cms plugin randomly renders one (and only one) of the inner placeholders.